# How to get the resource group via using the managed identity of the server-hosted function application?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I'm writing an Azure Function application in C# and am needing to detect the resource group in which the Function application is running. It's a Timer Trigger function and it's going to do some routine Resource Management operations for me.

The deployment model is such that we use resource groups as silos for different customers' resources - single-tenant-like. So I'd like to be able to dynamically detect the resource group in which the Function application is running instead of having to introduce configuration values telling the application that information.

I have the below code that is able to start with the subscription of the resource's identity, I assume, but then to get the resource group I have to supply a name.

Is there any way to just figure out which resource group this Function application is running in?

```
log.LogInformation($"Initializing Azure client ...");

var client = new ArmClient(new DefaultAzureCredential());

log.LogInformation("Fetching subscription and resource group ...");

var subscription = await client.GetDefaultSubscriptionAsync();
var resourceGroup = await subscription.GetResourceGroupAsync("NAME");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `WEBSITE_RESOURCE_GROUP` environment variable set in all app service environments that you can read directly.

Here is a [complete list of similar environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/reference-app-settings) available for reference.